# change font direction in word with python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I want to get a text from a word doc and make some change to it and put it into a new word doc

how can I change direction to Right-to-Lift and font size to 35

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document("nameOfTheFile.docx")
doc2 = Document()
n = 0
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    n += 1
    # doc2.add_paragraph(p.text)
    print(n)
doc2.save("nameOfTheFileEdited.docx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work using this -

Also [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882611/how-to-set-right-to-left-for-text-in-word-using-python-docx) -

```
import docx
from docx.shared import Pt

doc = docx.Document('file_name.docx')
doc1 = docx.Document()
style = doc1.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.rtl = True
font.size = Pt(35)
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    parag = doc1.add_paragraph()
    parag.add_run(paragraph.text)
    

doc1.save('new_file.docx')
```